# Конференция в freeswitch

Tags: sip, телефония

Хочу реализовать такой алгоритм:

- "Первый" звонит на номер 81002
- На экстеншане срезается 8 с номера (это в примерах есть) и создается конференция.
- В конференцию добавтиь "Второго" по номеру 1002 (пока через conference_set_auto_outcall)
- Второй берет трубку
- После того как второй взял трубку добавляется "Первый" - тоесть делается answer
- Закончить конференцию когда Второй выйдет

Конференция делается для того чтоб подмешать видео с внешнего источника.

Answer (score 0):

```
<extension name="extension-intercom">
  <condition field="destination_number" expression="^8([0-9]{3})$">
    <action application="set" data="dialed_extension=$1"/>

    <action application="conference" 
          data="bridge:${dialed_extension}@video-intercom:user/${dialed_extension}@$${domain_name}"
      />
    <action application="answer"/>
    <action application="answer"/>

  </condition>
</extension>
```